# Use another menu when logged in

Tags: menus, login

Before the update to WP 3.6 I could add this code in the header.php of the theme, which made it possible to have another menu when logged in:

```
        <?php
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $menu = 'logged-in';
        } else {
            $menu = 'logged-out';
        }

        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => $menu,
            'theme_location'    => 'menu',
            'sort_column'       => 'menu_order',
            'menu_class'        => 'sf-menu',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'default_menu'
        )); ?>
```

I have made the two menus called "logged-in" and "logged-out" in the WP admin panel.

But after the update, this doesn't work anymore. How can I change the menu when logged in in the correct way?

*(PS: The theme is WPExplorer's Adapt theme.)*

**Note:**

Actually, all I need is to change one specific button in the menu, so it is different when the user is logged in - in that case that menu button will be a "Member profile" button instead of a "Log in" button. If that can be done without changing the entire menu, that would be much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually, all I need is to change one specific button in the menu, so
>   it is different when the user is logged in - in that case that menu
>   button will be a "Member profile" button instead of a "Log in" button

Yes, you can use only one menu, assuming its slug is 'my_menu' do not add to it member profile nor login url, instead use `wp_nav_menu_{$menu_slug}_items` filter:

```
// 'my_menu' in filter name is the slug of the menu
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_my_menu_items', 'menu_add_admin_buttons', 20, 2); 

function menu_add_admin_buttons( $items, $args ) {
  $btn_format = '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>';
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $btn = sprintf($btn_format, admin_url('profile.php'), __('Your Profile') );
  } else {
    $btn = sprintf($btn_format, wp_login_url(), __('Log In') );
  }
  return $items . $btn;
}
```

`$items` are the current html for the current menu items, a string containg a series of `<li><a ... </a></li>`.

The slug of the menu is equal to `sanitize_title($menu_name)` i.e. it removes all special chars, converted accented chars with non accented ones and convert spaces to `-`.

E.g. if the name is "Main Menu" the slug is "main-menu".

The name your menu is called is what you write in wp backend when you create menu, see image below.

[image]

Of course is possible use `sanitize_title` to create the filter dinamically from name, e.g.

```
$menu_filter = 'wp_nav_menu_' . sanitize_title("Main Menu") . '_items';
add_filter($menu_filter, 'menu_add_admin_buttons', 20, 2);
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work... The menu slug will be the manually set menu name, right? What does the first argument `$items` do?

Comment: It seems the problem is different. My child theme doesn't work - it simply isn't used/added to the main theme. The `functions.php` as well as the `header.php` file in the child theme don't change anything. That is of course the cause. So that must be sorted out first...

Comment: @Steeven Tested, it works perfectly. I've added some explainations to answer.

Comment: @Steeven to test child theme try to insert `die('Test');` in your child theme `functions.php`. If the white screen with the only word 'Test' doesn't appear on site open you have a problem with the `style.css` file of your child theme, or the child theme is not the one activated in the backend.

Comment: Child theme working again! And your code works perfect. Thanks alot for answer and the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the theme location as well. How are you registering the menus? You could try this..

functions.php

```
<?php
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'logged-in'  => 'Logged In Nav',
        'logged-out' => 'Logged Out Nav'
    ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
?>
```

header.php

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $menu      = 'logged-in';
    $menu_name = 'Logged In Nav';
} else {
    $menu      = 'logged-out';
    $menu_name = 'Logged Out Nav';
} ?>

<nav role="navigation">
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => $menu_name,
        'theme_location'    => $menu,
        'sort_column'       => 'menu_order',
        'menu_class'        => 'sf-menu',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'default_menu'
    ));
    ?>
</nav>
```

Not tested, just an idea.

Also if you want to try it with one menu like you mentioned, you could use the body classes to target those specific links.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will add classes to the body and if a user is logged in it will add a 'logged-in' class. There isn't a logged-out class so you could hide the one you want to show only to logged in users then display it when they are logged in.

```
.menu-item-101 { /* hide for logged out users */
    display: none;
}

.logged-in .menu-item-101 { /* show for logged in users */
    display: block;
}

.logged-in .menu-item-102 { /* only show to logged out users */
    display: none;
}
```